# How to input user id and password in pop ups using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation

I am getting this browser pop-up while accessing a website. How can I fill username and password using Selenium with Python?

[image]

I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For browser popup sign in, try sending username and password in URL request:

```
url = f"http://{username}:{password}@example.com"
driver.get(url)
```